# Scraping the rating of some reviews as pictures

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the rating of some movie reviews but the rating is not a number, but it is one of 10 different images that range from showing empty stars to full stars.

This is the website where I scrape the data from:
https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/avatar-17818/reviews/?pagina=1&order_direction=DESC

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/avatar-17818/reviews/?pagina=1&order_direction=DESC'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

rating=0
scraped_ratings = soup.find_all('span', class_='stelutze').find=("img")
for i in scraped_ratings:
    if "star_full.gif" in i.get("src"):
        rating += 1
print(rating)
```

Somebody helped me with this code but it only gives the rating of the first review.

```
rating=0
rawRating = soup.find("span", {"class": "stelutze"}).find_all("img")
for i in rawRating:
    if "star_full.gif" in i.get("src"):
        rating += 1
print(rating)
```

I tried to change the code to this:

```
rating=0
count=0
rawRating = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "stelutze"}).find_all("img")
for i in rawRating:
    if "star_full.gif" in i.get("src"):
        rating += 1
    count+= 1
    if count == 10:
        print(rating)
        rating=0
        count=0
```

But I get this error:
`AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

I think this is because I can't use two find_all in the same statement.

Any help?

Update.
Now the code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pageNum = 1
for k in range (1,17):
    url = f'https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/avatar-17818/reviews/?pagina={pageNum}&order_direction=DESC'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    scraped_movies = soup.find_all('div', class_='left comentariu')
    movies = []
    for movie in scraped_movies:
        movies.append(movie.get_text().strip())

    reviewCount = -1
    rating = 0
    count = 0
    rawRatings = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "stelutze"})
    for i in rawRatings:
        rawRating = i.find_all("img")
        for j in rawRating:
            if "star_full.gif" in j.get("src"):
                rating += 1
            count += 1
            if count == 10:
                reviewCount += 1
                print(rating)
                print(movies[reviewCount])
                rating = 0
                count = 0
    pageNum += 1
```

The only problem is: In movies I have all the reviews but not all the reviews have a rating. In RawRatings have all the ratings.
I want to print each rating followed by it's respective review but when at some point I encounter a review without a rating I will just give it the rating that is next in line, messing up everything from that point on.

Any idea on how to see if a movie from movies has no rating? So that way I could increment reviewCount by 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this should solve your issue, I have not tested this but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Basically, when you do find_all you get a list back of all the elements it finds. So what it is doing is it first gets every review on the page and then you iterate over each review and get all the images for each review like you did before.

```
rating=0
count=0
rawRatings = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "stelutze"})
for i in rawRatings:
    rawRating = i.find_all("img")
    for j in rawRating:
        if "star_full.gif" in j.get("src"):
            rating += 1
        count += 1
        if count == 10:
            print(rating)
            rating = 0
            count = 0
```

If you have any questions let me know

Comment: Sheesh man thanks you very much. I would have one more thing that is not related exactly to this question tho. How could I get the ratings from all the pages? This is only page 1. Notice how in the URL there is a pagina=1 somewhere.

Comment: So in python you can use f strings which allow you to easily insert a variable into a string so you could do `pageNum = 1
url = f'https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/avatar-17818/reviews/?pagina={pageNum}&order_direction=DESC'` That would allow you to insert a page number into the URL. Then to get the total pages you could get that from the bottom of the page where it has the page numbers and get the final one so for your example it's 16 so just use a for loop and increase pageNum 16 times

Comment: Yea so I would make a loop from 1 to the max number of pages and update the URL each time. I am thinking about extracting the last page's number from the HTML of the site, it being the last value of the div class="clearfix mt10 box_paginare" so I don't have to manually insert the number of pages each time. I'll try this later since I am a little busy now but thank you again and I'll keep you up to date if I run into more problems

Comment: Hello again! I edited my post. I would appreciate if you took a look at it!